# How do I interpret an over identifying restrictions test for generalized method of moments (GMM) that produces a matrix?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, panel-data, vector-autoregression

I am estimating a panel VAR using dynamic panel data models (DPD) like Arellano and Bond (1991). I would like to test the adequateness of the possible specifications through an over identifying restrictions test. The problem resides in the fact that when you put DPD models in a VAR framework the standard Sargan-Hansen test produces a matrix of dimension kxk, where k is the number of variables in the VAR. For instance, if I estimate a panel VAR with 2 variables and 1 lag the Sargan-Hansen test will produce a 2x2 matrix.

My questions are:

1. How do I interpret this matrix?
2. Is there a way in which I can collapse this matrix into a scalar usable as a test statistic?

Comment: Please spell out your acronyms. What do you mean by "GMM", *Gaussian Mixture Model*, *Generalized Method of Moments*, something else?

Comment: With GMM I mean generalized method of moments.